# How can I use vscode setStatusBarMessage with hideWhenDone?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried to find a simple example of using the Thenable hideWhenDone parameter for `vscode.window.setStatusBarMessage` but I was not able to find one.

Can someone point to a simple example where the message is hidden after waiting a number of seconds? (simulating an operation that would run in background).

Answer (score 0):

```
    context.subscriptions.push(
      vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.showWaitStatus', () => {
        vscode.window.setStatusBarMessage('Wait till work is done!', new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => { resolve(true); }, 5000);
        }))
      })
    );
```